# Change baseboard serial

Tags: serial-number, motherboard

I'm looking for any possible way to change baseboard serial programmatically.
I should do that under Vista or Win 7, ideally it should be for any model, not specific.
Actually, I could solve downloading any special tool from baseboard manufacturer or using DOS.
But this I will do in case I won't find any other possible way.

I know that there is a special application dmicfg.exe that allows you to edit DMI area in BIOS. But I'm not sure it works in vista and Win7. 
If I could even find such solution that would be nice also.

Comment: Motherboards have serial numbers? This may be specific to a certain brand and model. Can you please give a bit more detail? Software manufacturers often use the MAC address of the onboard (or connected) Ethernet adapter instead, as these are (usually) unique.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you need? What kind of baseboard? In what programming language and environment? Can you show us what you've attempted so far? We *really* struggle on vague questions on this ($5 says someone posts an answer before you edit though).

Comment: @Carl, Yes, Motherboards have serial numbers, but not all motherboards have it. depends on the manufacturer

Comment: Told you. That'll be $5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most server systems will allow the programming of the serial number for the motherboard. The value is typically set during the manufacturing process, but can be set using something like the intel deployment assistant CD (different ones for different systems).
Occasionally, the BIOS update process for server systems will also include the ability to set these values. Again, very baseboard dependent.
You may be able to find an appropriate deployment CD on the intel web site which may allow you to set these values. Again, these would be for intel baseboards. Boards from other manufacturers would have a different process.
Hope this helps you find some information to guide you to the appropriate solution.

Comment: Have you ever heard about AMT (advanced management technology)? Can this help?

Comment: I don't think it supports setting such information as the baseboard serial number. For management it's pretty good - the remote virtual CD booting is an excellent way to re-provision systems.